# Disable RTL on specific UIViewController in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, localization, left-to-right

Is there any way to disable Right-to-Left in specific ViewController? I have tried forcing semanticContentAttribute to Left-to-Right but it is not working.

```
self.view.semanticContentAttribute = .forceLeftToRight
```

Answer (score -1):

Add this code in your view did load  -:

```
 UIView.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = .forceLeftToRight
```

Comment: This will change the whole application not specific ViewController

Comment: when you add this code on specific controller then it will change only specific view controller View.

Comment: can you show your code